# PHP require_once Absolute Path vs Relative Path (Not Working)

Tags: php, require

Well, I am still very confused how this is possible. Look at the following two lines of code:

> Code on **Connection.php** in **class** folder:

```
require_once '../config/constants.php';

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/config/constants.php';
```

The second works totally fine, but the first throws the error of:

```
No such file in ...... on line... in Connection.php
```

It's getting on my nerves, what is the difference between the two? In my years of programming, I never encountered such problem? Am I missing some points?

> If you have any documentation you would like to offer then provide. I would like to have a good
>   foundation of knowledge than just solving problem.

Directory Structure:

[image]

Comment: Remove the `../` part from your first include and change it to: `./`

Comment: @Rizier123, Any documentation you would like to offer? I would like to have a good foundation of knowledge than just solving problem

Comment: `../` means parent directory `./` a relative path from your current directory

Comment: @Rizier123 but see the directory structure, I have the file on another folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`../` denotes the *parent* directory, compared to the one you're currently in. Therefore, your first line says "go one directory up and look for *config/constants.php* in there". What you'd want to use with a relative path here is `./` (note the single dot), which denotes your current directory.

This has little to do with programming in specific, it's more of a file-system thing.

You can use this as a reference:

- leading `/` (no dots, just a slash) means an absolute path
- leading `./` (single dot) means the current directory
- leading `../` (two dots) means one directory up
- no leading dots or slashes is the same thing as with the single dot - relative to the *current* directory.

**Update (to account for edited question):**

What *has* something to do with programming and PHP in particular is that what is considered the "current" directory is usually the one where you initially executed the script from.
Under a CLI environment, that may vary, but if you're accessing the script via the web that is the location of the PHP file which you have **directly** accessed. E.g. if you're pointing your browser to `example.com/test.php`, then wherever 'test.php' is located is the directory you're currently in.

That can be changed by `chdir()` of course.

Comment: but I have to go to the parent directory to access another folder, right? Please have a look at the Directory Structure.  **Accessing constants.php from Connection.php**